# How to initialize XMVECTOR in DirectX?

Tags: c++, directx

I am just starting to use DirectXMath. I want to use the 
Intersects function to check if two Triangles intersect. But everytime I call the function I get an exeption in it. I figure it is because I don´t create the XMVECTOR parameters the right way. I tried it two ways:

```
DirectX::XMVECTOR r = DirectX::XMVectorSet(m_x, m_y, m_z, 1.0f);
DirectX::XMVECTORI32 t = { m_x, m_y, m_z, 1.0f };
```

Both ways don´t work and since XMVECTOR doesn´t have x y z members I am having trouble understanding how this data type works.

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both variants are valid. If you are getting an exception you should post it here (along with the code to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Are these local variables or are they members? Post the exception/error, this could be an alignment issue

Answer (score 7):

Actually all the ways noted in the thread so far are valid ways, but have different uses and performance implications.

If you want to create a 'vectorized constant' of four floating-point constant values, the best answer is to use `XMVECTORF32`:

```
static const XMVECTORF32 s_MyValue = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f, 4.f };
```

The compiler is usually able to put this into the program's data segment so at runtime you just end up calling `MOVAPS` to get the data into a SSE register.

> The `XMVECTORU32` and `XMVECTORI32` types do the same thing but assuming you want to initialize the elements to either an `unsigned int` or an `int` typically for use with bitwise or select operations since the DirectXMath library doesn't implement more than a few integer operations.

If you are storing your data in memory, a good solution is to use `XMFLOAT4` in your data structures and use `XMLoadFloat4` to get it into an `XMVECTOR`:

```
XMVECTOR v = XMLoadFloat4(&myClass.myValue);
// This is equivalent in SSE to using _mm_loadu_ps
```

> The vast majority of types in the DirectXMath library are intended to use in data structures. You use `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX` for all the computation, using the load and save routines to get data into and out of those types.

If you need to set a vector from a set of 4 scalar floating-point variables, that's what `XMVectorSet` is for:

```
XMVECTOR v = XMVectorSet( m_x, m_y, m_y, 1.f );
// This is equivalent in SSE to using _mm_set_ps.
```

If you want a single scalar value loaded into all four positions, you'd use:

```
XMVECTOR v = XMVectorReplicate( m_a );
// This is equivalent in SSE to using _mm_set_ps1.
```

If you are wanting to load a scalar value into all four positions from a value in memory, another option is:

```
XMVECTOR v = XMVectorReplicatePtr( &m_a );
// This is equivalent in SSE to using _mm_load_ps1.
// If you were building with /arch:AVX, it would be _mm_broadcast_ss
```

There are also special-use case functions like `XMVectorSetX` / `XMVectorSetXPtr`, `XMVectorSetY` / `XMVectorSetYPtr`, `XMVectorSetZ` / `XMVectorSetZPtr`, `XMVectorSetW` / `XMVectorSetWPtr`, and the rather slow `XMVectorSetByIndex` / `XMVectorSetIndexPtr`.

If you are new to DirectXMath, take some time to read through the [DirectXMath Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415571.aspx). It's not particularly long and it's packed with information and tips.

See also [Introducing DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) and my other [blog posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/tag/xnamath/) onthe subject. Also be sure to check out the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/wiki).

> Some people find the SIMD-friendly alignment rules of DirectXMath a bit frustrating especially when they are first starting out, which is why I've also created the [SimpleMath wrapper](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) which is included in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki). In this case you'd use something like `Vector4 v( m_x, m_y, m_z, 1.f );` then you can use `v` wherever you'd use `XMVECTOR`.